# The number of answers I have written is different between my computer browser and my Quora Android app

Tags: quora

Quora Android app shows that I have written 639 answers, my computer browser says 636. Why?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a currently unfixed bug in Quora: the Android app is counting your reviews, which is why the answer is slightly higher.